# How can I accept bitcoin donations from my Android app?

Tags: java, android, bitcoin, donations

I know Google doesn't like developpers accepting donations but technically speaking how would I do it? For PayPal you just open a link. Is there an easy way to do it with Bitcoin?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/wiki/InAppPayments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a bitcoin URL that is handled by an installed bitcoin wallet, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886804/handling-unknown-uri-schemes-in-android-bitcoin-example) or you can use an existing payment platform (like paypal) that handles bitcoins (paypal does not).

[Here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_accept_Bitcoin,_for_small_businesses) you have a guide and a "Merchant Services" list. They will handle the payment.