# "No Activity found to handle Intent Error" while Exporting to CSV

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, export-to-csv

Hello I am trying to implement a way to export my database to csv file. But I am receiving this error.

```
2020-11-16 14:54:05.543 14666-14666/com.example.passwordhaven E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.passwordhaven, PID: 14666
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.example.passwordhaven.fileprovider/movies_csv_files/getCSVFileName.csv typ=text/comma-separated-values flg=0x3 }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
    at com.example.passwordhaven.ui.view.activities.PasswordHavenActivity.exportDatabaseToCSVFile(PasswordHavenActivity.kt:58)
    at com.example.passwordhaven.ui.view.activities.PasswordHavenActivity.access$exportDatabaseToCSVFile(PasswordHavenActivity.kt:23)
    at com.example.passwordhaven.ui.view.activities.PasswordHavenActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(PasswordHavenActivity.kt:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1115)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

My code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", file)
val mimeType = context.contentResolver.getType(contentUri)
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mimeType)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

return intent
```

I have cloned the example project which is supposed to work, it gave the same error. Is there anything with IDE or project libraries?[Example project](https://github.com/lomza/movies-room)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle the ActivityNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399065/how-to-handle-the-activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is when this code runs it tries to open .csv file. But the emulator does not have that file reader I think. The code works on an actual device.